# Memory Pools and <Unable to read memory>

Tags: c++, winapi

I recently switched my project to using a linear memory allocator that I wrote myself (for learning). When I initialize the allocator, I pass it a pointer to a block of memory that was VirtualAlloc-ed beforehand. Before writing the allocator, I was using this block directly just fine.

In my test case, I am using the allocator to allocate memory for a Player* in that initial big block of memory. To make sure every was working, I tried accessing the block of memory directly as I had before to make sure the values were changing according to my expectations. That's when I hit a memory access error. Using the VS debugger/watch window, I have a reasonable idea of what is happening and when, but I am hoping to get some help with the question of why. I'll lay out the relevant pieces of code below.

**Virtual Alloc call, later referred to by memory->transientStorage**

```
win32_State.gameMemoryBlock = VirtualAlloc(baseAddress, (size_t)win32_State.totalSize, 
                                                MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

**Allocator definition**

```
struct LinearAllocator {
    void* currentPos;
    size_t totalSize;
    void* startPos;
    size_t usedMemory;
    size_t numAllocations;

    LinearAllocator();
    LinearAllocator(size_t size, void* start);
    LinearAllocator(LinearAllocator&) = delete;
    ~LinearAllocator();

    void* allocate(size_t size, uint8 alignment);
    void clear();
};
```

**Player and Vec2f definitions**

```
struct Player {
    Vec2f pos;
    bool32 isFiring;
    real32 timeLastFiredMS;
};

union Vec2f {
    struct {
        real32 x, y;
    };
    real32 v[2];
};
```

**Relevant Allocator Implementation Details**

```
void* LinearAllocator::allocate(size_t size, uint8_t alignment) {
    if (size == 0 || !isPowerOfTwo(alignment)) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    uint8_t adjustment = alignForwardAdjustment(currentPos, alignment);
    if (usedMemory + adjustment + size > totalSize) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    uint8_t* alignedAddress = (uint8*)currentPos + adjustment;
    currentPos = (void*)(alignedAddress + size);
    usedMemory += size + adjustment;
    numAllocations++;

    return (void*)alignedAddress;
}

inline uint8_t alignForwardAdjustment(void* address, uint8_t alignment) {
    uint8_t adjustment = alignment - ( (size_t)address & (size_t)(alignment - 1));
    if (adjustment == alignment) {
        return 0; // already aligned
    }

    return adjustment;
}

inline int32_t isPowerOfTwo(size_t value) {
    return value != 0 && (value & (value - 1)) == 0;
}
```

**Initialization code where I attempt to use allocator**

```
// **Can write to memory fine here**
((float*)memory->transientStorage)[0] = 4.f;

size_t simulationAllocationSize = memory->transientStorageSize / 2 / sizeof(real32);
simulationMemory = LinearAllocator(simulationAllocationSize, &memory->transientStorage + (uint8_t)0);

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PLAYERS; i++) {
    Player* p = (Player*)simulationMemory.allocate(sizeof(Player), 4);

    // **also works here**
    ((real32*)memory->transientStorage)[0] = 3.f;
    p->pos.x = 0.f; // **after this line, I got the unable to read memory error**
    p->pos.y = 0.f;
    p->isFiring = false;
    p->timeLastFiredMS = 0.f;
    // **can't write **
    ((real32*)memory->transientStorage)[0] = 1.f;
}

// **also can't write**
((real32*)memory->transientStorage)[0] = 2.f;
real32 test = ((real32*)memory->transientStorage)[0];
```

My running assumption is that I'm missing something obvious. But the only clue I have to go off of is that it changed after setting a value in the Player struct. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked to see whether the value of the pointer  `memory` or of the pointer `memory->transientStorage` is changing?

Comment: I have that up in my watch window. That's how I'm tracking when the memory becomes unreadable. It changes as expected until the line p->pos.x = 0.f;

Comment: What do you mean, "changes as expected?  So far as I can see from the code, both the `memory` and `memory->transientStorage` pointers should be constant.  Perhaps you'd better show the declaration for `memory`.

Comment: ... are you watching the value *at* the pointer rather than the value *of* the pointer?

Comment: To be clearer. I have this in my watch window: ((real32*)memory->transientStorage)[0]. When I say changes as expected, when the code tells it to change from 4 to 3, it changes from 4 to 3. Then it hits the error. The actual memory block itself is constant though.

Comment: OK, so add `memory->transientStorage` to your watch window.  When the error occurs, does it still have the same value it did beforehand?

Comment: When I put that in the watch window, it just displays 0x000000000. If I put in (real32*)memory->transientStorage, 4 it shows me 4 instances of <Unable to read memory>

Comment: also instead `alignForwardAdjustment` you can use `newPos=(currentPos + alignment-1)&~(alignment-1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is your problem:

```
simulationMemory = LinearAllocator(simulationAllocationSize, 
   &memory->transientStorage + (uint8_t)0);
```

There's a stray `&` operator, causing you to allocate memory not from the allocated memory block that `memory->transientStorage` points to but from wherever `memory` itself lives.

This is turns causes the write to `p->pos.x` to overwrite the value of `transientStorage`.

The call to LinearAllocator should be just

```
simulationMemory = LinearAllocator(simulationAllocationSize, 
   memory->transientStorage + (uint8_t)0);
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that! I had mistakenly done that instead of casting to uint8 for some pointer addition. I had a week between when I introduced that bug and now and apparently completely forgotten I had done so.